# Can Not Delete with `rm` command

Tags: pi-3b+

So I'm trying to build a web server on my raspberry pi at the moment, and need to delete the index.html folder with rm but can not, I'm now trying to replace the file with a PHP one so please help me

Comment: P.S NOT A NEWCOMER

Comment: You likely don't own the directory so you will need to prepend your command with sudo.

Comment: Would you please copy the entire error that you get when trying to delete the file?

Comment: In addition to copying the error, please show us the output of `ls -la /path/to/index/html`

Comment: pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo rm index.html
rm: cannot remove 'index.html': No such file or directory
pi@raspberrypi:~ $

Comment: @BobBrown -rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 10701 Dec 18 17:19 /var/www/html/index.html

Comment: what is the output of `ls` command?

Comment: Are you in the directory /var/www/html when you issue the command to delete index.html ?

Comment: Please don't use comments for additional information. It's unreadable. Instead edit your question and add it there. Not all user will read the comments to understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based om your responses in comments, it looks like user pi is in the home directory.  Try this: `rm /var/www/html/index.html`  You shouldn't even need sudo for that because the index.html file is owned by user pi.

**Edit:** What actually worked was `sudo rm /var/www/html/index.html`  I guess, but am not certain, that `sudo` was required because the /var/ directory is owned by root, not pi.

Comment: Permission denied.

Comment: @JacRhisiart Well, I don't understand that, but try it prefixed by sudo, please, *i.e.* `sudo rm /var/www/html/index.html`